# generating matched and unmatched IDs after merging to datasets

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

Using the code below, I could merge my two datasets. I would like to generate a column containing the cases that 1) successfully merged, 2) cases that did not successfully merge because their corresponding IDs were not available in the master data (projimpl), and 3) cases that did not successfully merge because their corresponding IDs were not available in the using data (projects). My column of interest is automatically generated in Stata after merging two datasets but looks like it is not the case in R.

**Here is my merging code:**

```
projects<- merge(projimpl,projects, by="ProjectID", all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably multiple ways to do this. One way is to use `dplyr::anti_join`, which is a useful filtering join from the dplyr package [see here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter-joins.html).
I could not test it because I don't have your data, but something like below should work:

```
library(dplyr)

mergeddata<- merge(projimpl,projects, by="ProjectID", all = TRUE)

IDsNotInMaster <- anti_join(projects, projimpl, by="ProjectID")$ProjectID  
IDsNotInProjects <- anti_join(projimpl,projects, by="ProjectID")$ProjectID

newdata <- mergeddata %>% 
  mutate(
    case = case_when(
      ProjectID %in% IDsNotInMaster   ~ "ID only in Project data",
      ProjectID %in% IDsNotInProjects ~ "ID only in Master data",
      TRUE                            ~ "Successfully merged"
        )
  )
newdata
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful solution! I wonder how to add a column in the merged data so I can see what ProjectIDs are not successfully merged!

Comment: @NaderMehri I tried to accomplish that with the last part of the code. it will add a column named "case" to your dataset. I changed the names in this new column now to make it clearer. Note that you can also use base R `ifelse` instead of `case_when` for creating the column. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I made another edit because I was not aware that your merged dataset had the same name as one of the datasets that you are merging with. I hope it works now.